# VS403250: The dacpac or source database is not a detached TFS Collection database

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration

I am working on migrating the projects from on premise TFS Server to VSTS, for that I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/articles/migration-import).

But when I run this command `TfsMigrator import /importFile:C:\TFSDataImportFiles\import.json`, I got the error like **VS403250: The dacpac or source database is not a detached TFS Collection database** even though I detached the collection from my on premise TFS server.

[image]

Can you please tell me how to resolve the above error as soon as possible?

Comment: I am re-try, But same error is coming. VS403250: The dacpac or source database is not a detached TFS Collection database

Comment: Are there any other error messages in event viewer? I suggest you cleaning the caches then reboot the App Tier server, then try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I got confused with the difference between detaching the database and detaching the collection. You have to detach he collection from either the TFS admin console or the tfsconfig command line utility on the application tier. I prefer the command line. FYI: My first attempt to re-attach the collection using the admin console got hung up and appeared to run for six hours before I restarted the app tier and it finally errored out. Attaching a 160 GB collection with 48 projects only took a few minutes when it worked correctly using tfsconfig.

You create your dacpac or backup the collection after detaching the collection. Then if it is a dry run, re- attach the collection.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [troubleshooting document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-troubleshooting) you need to detach the collection database, then generate the DACPAC again.

> VS403250: The dacpac is not a detached TFS Collection database.
>
> The DACPAC is not built off a detached collection. The collection
>   database will need to be [**detached**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-import#detaching-your-collection) and the DACPAC generated again.